# How to call a function(only one not all) inside a plugin from outside in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a function i.e.

```
 SFProductFilter.prototype.filter = function () {
    //Some Code which also interact with some of other plugin functions
 }
```

From outside of the plugin. Is it possible if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless I'm totally missing something:

```
SFProductFilter.prototype.filter()
```